# JavaScript web app can't find element to insert text

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When entering the numbers into the textbox to get the stories it works just fine until I type in number "4" and hit the "Get Story" button and try to go back to number 3. That's when I get this message in the console window on line 35:

"Generated text element not found."

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Story Fetcher</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Stories</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <div id="get-container">
                <input type="text" id="story-number" placeholder="Enter story number">
                <button id="get">Get Story</button>
                <button id="getRandom">Random Story</button>
            </div>
            <div id="story-container">
                <div id="generated-text"></div>
                <button id="clear">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #ff6600;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 28px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        main {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            min-height: 80vh;
        }

        #content-wrapper {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            padding: 20px;
            max-width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #story-number {
            padding: 10px 16px;
            font-size: 14px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #get-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #get, #getRandom, #clear {
            background-color: #ff6600;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 4px;
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #story-container {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            padding: 20px;
            max-width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
        }

        #generated-text {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            color: #333;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #generated-text span {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        #clear {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        @media (min-width: 601px) {
            #content-wrapper {
                max-width: 600px;
                max-height: 40vh;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            #get, #clear {
                font-size: 10px !important;
                padding: 20px 20px !important;
            }
        }
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var totalStories = 3;
    var currentStory = null;

    function clearStoryContainer() {
        var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');
        if (storyContainer) {
            storyContainer.style.display = 'none';
            var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
            if (generatedTextElement) {
                generatedTextElement.innerHTML = '';
            }
            var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
            if (contentWrapper) {
                contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '0';
            }
            currentStory = null;
        }
    }

    function fetchStory(storyNumber) {
        clearStoryContainer();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'fetch.php?story=' + storyNumber, true);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');
                if (storyContainer) {
                    storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
                    var generatedText = xhr.responseText;
                    var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
                    if (generatedTextElement) {
                        generatedTextElement.innerHTML = parseAndStyleTitles(generatedText);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Generated text element not found.');
                    }
                    var contentWrapper = document.getElementById('content-wrapper');
                    if (contentWrapper) {
                        contentWrapper.style.marginTop = '60px';
                    } else {
                        console.log('Content wrapper element not found.');
                    }
                    currentStory = storyNumber;
                } else {
                    console.log('Story container element not found.');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Error fetching story. Status code: ' + xhr.status);
                clearStoryContainer();
                displayErrorMessage('Error fetching story.');
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            console.log('Network error while fetching story.');
            clearStoryContainer();
            displayErrorMessage('Network error while fetching story.');
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

    function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
        var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');
        storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
        storyContainer.innerHTML = errorMessage;
        document.getElementById('content-wrapper').style.marginTop = '60px';
        currentStory = null;
    }

    function parseAndStyleTitles(text) {
        return text.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, function (match, title) {
            return '<span>' + title + '</span>';
        });
    }

    document.getElementById('get').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var storyNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('story-number').value);

        if (!isNaN(storyNumber) && storyNumber >= 1 && storyNumber <= totalStories) {
            fetchStory(storyNumber);
        } else {
            displayErrorMessage('Please enter a valid number between 1 and ' + totalStories + '.');
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('getRandom').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var randomStoryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalStories) + 1;
        fetchStory(randomStoryNumber);
    });

    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
        clearStoryContainer();
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Read the requested story number from the URL parameter
$storyNumber = $_GET['story'];

// Check if the story number is valid (e.g., within the range of available stories)
$totalStories = 3; // Update this to match the actual total number of stories

if ($storyNumber >= 1 && $storyNumber <= $totalStories) {
    // Read the content of stories.txt
    $storiesFile = file_get_contents('stories.txt');

    // Split the content into stories based on a unique delimiter (e.g., "###")
    $stories = explode("###", $storiesFile);

    // Get the requested story
    $requestedStory = trim($stories[$storyNumber - 1]); // Adjust the array index

    // Replace newline characters with <br> tags for line breaks
    $formattedStory = nl2br($requestedStory);

    // Return the formatted story as a response
    echo $formattedStory;
} else {
    // Return an error message if the story number is invalid
    echo 'Error: Invalid story number.';
}
?>
```

**stories.txt**

```
1. [[IDAHO: The Bear Lake Monster]]

    In the depths of Bear Lake, a legend born from Joseph C. Rich's pen lurks—a tale of the enigmatic "Bear Lake Monster." This 20th-century legend, chronicled by Rich, tells of an elusive creature with sightings of a colossal, malevolent "water devil." Its elongated neck, capable of striking from the water's edge, added to its mystique.

    Through generations, tales of the Bear Lake Monster echoed in the region, whispered around campfires and passed down. The lake's murky depths became a realm of fear and fascination, where the line between reality and legend blurred.

    Recent events added a twist—a 25-foot-long decomposed carcass found on the lake's shores. Some claim it to be the creature of centuries-old sightings, sparking intrigue and mystery.
    The legend of the Bear Lake Monster, rooted in both the written word and local memory, continues to cast its eerie shadow over the tranquil waters of the lake, serving as a reminder of the enduring allure of the unknown and the power of myth in the human experience.

###  <!-- Unique delimiter separating stories -->
2. [[DELAWARE: The Addy-Sea Inn]]

    Nestled on Bethany Beach's serene shores, the Addy-Sea Inn, dating back to 1902, exudes timeless elegance and history. Yet, beneath its historic exterior lies a tapestry of paranormal encounters and unexplained phenomena.

    Three specific rooms within the inn are rumored to house restless spirits. In Room 1, guests have reported the antique porcelain tub shaking mysteriously during baths, as though stirred by unseen hands. Room 6 resonates with ethereal organ music despite the absence of instruments, creating an enchanting yet enigmatic atmosphere.

    Room 11, however, emerges as the epicenter of these ghostly tales, rumored to be haunted by the spirit of Paul Dulaney, the inn's former handyman. His spectral presence occasionally materializes near the bed, blurring the boundaries between the living and the departed.

    As guests step into the historic Addy-Sea Inn, they anticipate encounters with the spectral. Within its hallowed halls, the living and the otherworldly intersect, offering a unique opportunity to commune with the spirits of yesteryear and engage in the timeless dance between the seen and the unseen.

###  <!-- Unique delimiter separating stories -->

3. [[Inn of the Goblin]]

    Nestled on Bethany Beach's serene shores, the Addy-Sea Inn, dating back to 1902, exudes timeless elegance and history. Yet, beneath its historic exterior lies a tapestry of paranormal encounters and unexplained phenomena.

    Three specific rooms within the inn are rumored to house restless spirits. In Room 1, guests have reported the antique porcelain tub shaking mysteriously during baths, as though stirred by unseen hands. Room 6 resonates with ethereal organ music despite the absence of instruments, creating an enchanting yet enigmatic atmosphere.

    Room 11, however, emerges as the epicenter of these ghostly tales, rumored to be haunted by the spirit of Paul Dulaney, the inn's former handyman. His spectral presence occasionally materializes near the bed, blurring the boundaries between the living and the departed.

    As guests step into the historic Addy-Sea Inn, they anticipate encounters with the spectral. Within its hallowed halls, the living and the otherworldly intersect, offering a unique opportunity to commune with the spirits of yesteryear and engage in the timeless dance between the seen and the unseen.
```

Why is this occurring? Do I need to change anything?

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In displayErrorMessage function, you use innerHTML for story-container. When the error message load, the div with id="generated-text" will be replaced, so when you try to show one story again, there is no div with id="generated-text" to show the story.

You just need to show error message in generated-text or use another div.

```
function displayErrorMessage(errorMessage) {
        var storyContainer = document.getElementById('story-container');
        storyContainer.style.display = 'block';
        var generatedTextElement = document.getElementById('generated-text');
        generatedTextElement.innerHTML = errorMessage;
        document.getElementById('content-wrapper').style.marginTop = '60px';
        currentStory = null;
    }
```

story.txt

```
1. [[IDAHO: The Bear Lake Monster]]
...............................
    
###2. [[DELAWARE: The Addy-Sea Inn]]
..................................

###3. [[Inn of the Goblin]]
...................................
```

Comment: What would be a good way to change this?

Comment: I think I managed to fix it. But now there's the next issue, the first story generates just fine, but then the next story generates a bit further down leaving quite a bit of space on the top.

Comment: I edit my answer, replace the displayErrorMessage function that i send with yours, and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Yes, that helped! But now there's the next issue, the first story generates just fine, but then the next story generates a bit further down leaving quite a bit of space on the top. And then the third goes even further down.

Comment: Because in your story.txt file, you are using 1 newline for story 2 and 2 newline for story 3, for fixing the problem you have to remove newlines from stories.

Comment: What do you mean by "removing newlines" ?

Comment: I edit my answer, saw the story.txt part. You have to edit your stories like this to remove extra lines.

Comment: Thing is, I need the blank lines to make it as paragraphs.

Comment: Just remove newline after ### and before number. Also, it would be nice if select my answer as final answer.

Comment: I'm quite new to Stack Overflow, so don't really know how to do that.

Also, when I press any of the buttons now, there seem to be some kind of a blinking effect going on for a second or so, any idea what causes this?

Comment: You did it and the answer is selected, thanks. Also, did my last comment fix your problem ?

Comment: Not really, but I found a fix in the PHP. But the blinking issue still exist where it blinks for a second whenever I press any of the buttons to generate a story.

Comment: For fix that, you can learn and use jQuery and callback function to control each move in browser.

Comment: It would take me quite long to learn jQuery and callback functions, so if you could help me with this I would be very, very thankful!

Comment: Sure, but you need to open a new question and describe what you want.

Comment: This issue has been resolved, but can't delete this question.

Comment: You don't need to delete this question, it will remain for future users that may have the same problem.

Comment: Somehow I've been banned from creating new questions, and I'm not sure how to resolve that :/

Comment: That's because you're asking too many questions ! Generally you have to dig in and after a couple of days if you are not success, then try to send new question.

Comment: Hanif, I think question bans are applied if a poster asks too many **downvoted** questions. Thus, the number of questions doesn't matter - if some of them were upvoted then the author would be permitted to ask more. [See this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) on Meta. cc @PatrikQvarnström.